# Grouping a grouped column without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think this can be easier to explain with an example so let's say we have a database like this:

- The first table is `Interventions`, which stores the Id and whatever it
  needs.
- The second one is `Doctors`.
- The third one is `Tools`.
- The fourth one is an N-N table, which matches each Intervention with all its
  doctors, let's call it `DoctorsOnInterventions`
- The fifth one is another N-N table, which matches each Tool used on each intervention, let's call it `ToolsOnInterventions`

Ok, now we can do:

```
SELECT InterventionId, STRING_AGG(Doctors.Name, ', ')
FROM Interventions
INNER JOIN Doctors ON Doctors.Id = DoctorsOnInterventions.DoctorId
GROUP BY Intervention.Id, Doctors.Id;
```

And get:

```
+-----------------+------------+
| InterventionId  |  Doctors   |
+-----------------+------------+
|               1 | Tom, John  |
|               2 | Tom, Homer |
+-----------------+------------+
```

But we need to add another column, just like Doctors, but with the tools used in that intervention, something like this:

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| InterventionId  |  Doctors   |      Tools      |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|               1 | Tom, John  | Scalpel, Hammer |
|               2 | Tom, Homer | Hammer, Bulb    |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

It would be easy to do wrapping the previous code on a subquery and then making another `group by`, but I was wondering if there was a more correct way to make this as my database tables have a few tens of columns.

Comment: What is the `STRING()` function?

Comment: That is not valid t-sql. I don't know of any version of sql that has STRING as a function. How about some table definitions, sample data, and something valid for a query?

Comment: What kind of relation exist between the tables Interventions and Tools? You can only related tables if how have at least one column between them

Comment: @GordonLinoff fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT InterventionId, STRING(Doctors.Name, ', '),STRING(Tools.name,',')
FROM Interventions
INNER JOIN Doctors ON Doctors.Id = DoctorsOnInterventions.DoctorId 
INNER JOIN Tools on tools.id = ToolsOnInterventions.toolsid
GROUP BY Intervention.Id, Doctors.Id, tools.id;
```

Comment: If you group by those 3, youll get for each doctor all tool combinations used, that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_agg()`.  I would recommend subqueries; `apply` can be used:

```
SELECT i.*, d.doctors, t.tools
FROM Interventions i OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT STRING_AGG(d.name, ',') as doctors
      FROM DoctorsOnInterventions doi JOIN
           Doctors d
           ON d.Id = doi.DoctorId
      WHERE doi.interventionId = i.id
     ) d OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT STRING_AGG(t.name, ',') as tools
      FROM ToolsOnInterventions toi JOIN
           Tools t
           ON t.id = toi.ToolId
      WHERE toi.interventionId = i.id
     ) t ;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you can use the `FOR XML PATH` method of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need another table to related then.

Table Interventions

```
+-----------------+------------+
| InterventionId  |  Doctors   |
+-----------------+------------+
|               1 | Tom, John  |
|               2 | Tom, Homer |
+-----------------+------------+
```

Table Tools

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| InterventionId  |  Doctors       |
+-----------------+----------------+
|               1 | Scalpel, Hammer|
|               2 | Hammer, Bulb   |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

Table Interventions_tool (**new**)

```
+-----------------+------------+
| InterventionId  |  ToolId    |
+-----------------+------------+
|               1 | 1          |
|               2 | 2          |
+-----------------+------------+
```

The query will be

```
SELECT InterventionId, STRING(Doctors.Name, ', ')
FROM Interventions I WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Doctors D WITH (NOLOCK) ON D.Id = I.DoctorId
INNER JOIN Interventions_tool IT WITH (NOLOCK) ON I.Id = IT.ToolId
GROUP BY I.Id, D.Id;

+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| InterventionId  |  Doctors   |      Tools      |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
|               1 | Tom, John  | Scalpel, Hammer |
|               2 | Tom, Homer | Hammer, Bulb    |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Yes, I writed it, I called It ToolsOnInterventios

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí I did not understand? Did you use the suggestion?